# Compare two pandas data frames and get differences

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am currently having two pandas data frames.

**df1** :- Parsing an excel an getting data in a data frame and inserting this into Postgresql db.

**df2**:- getting Postgresql table in a data frame.

Now I want to compare these both data frames and update the DB for only the changed cells in the df1 when I compare it with current DB(**df2**).

Can someone please tell how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df_diff=pd.DataFrame()
for column in df1.columns:
    df_diff[column]=~df1.column.isin(df2[column])
df1.where(df_diff, inplace=True)
```

Comment: df is df1. Sorry for the mistake. Please note than all columns name of df1 should be in df2 and with the same name

Comment: I am getting the error "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'"

Comment: df_diff[column]=~df1[column] .isin(df2[column])

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now that I got to know which particular cell is changed, how do I update the changed ones in db?? I mean how do I iterate?